# WordPress post images to be open in lightbox when clicked

Tags: jquery, wordpress, lightbox

I am just newbie to the `WordPress`. I want to know how to make the `images posted in post pages to be open in a lightbox when clicked?` Is there any good `plugins` which can make my work easier or any relevent codes which can help me to achive this. Any help and suggestions will be appreciable.

**[Update]**

Admin will not put any `link` or any `rel link`. He will just `upload,insert` the images in post pages.